# How do I remove an armor stand without destroying it (survival mode)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In MineCraft (friend's realm, survival, java v 16.5) How do I remove an armor stand without destroying it. I have removed all the armor from it, and find that the only way I can remove (turn it into an item in my inventory again) it is by attacking it until it is destroyed and re-crafting. This is wasteful and I would like to know if there is some special way to "pick it up".

Comment: Please don't answer questions in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally attacking the armorstand causes it to drop as an item - it doesn't need re-crafting, you can just place it wherever you want. Does your friend maybe have some datapacks or mods installed that change that behavior?

Comment: Not that I know of. Actually I have Fire Aspect on my sword, do you think that could be destroying it?

Comment: @funkymushroom Yes. Armorstands are flammable and setting them on fire will destroy them. Interestingly, if you attack the burning armorstand several times in quick succession, even with fire aspect you can drop it as an item. Or just punch them a lot with anything that doesn't set them on fire.

Comment: Thanks @SF, appreciate the quick response. I will test this out tonight.

Comment: Thanks for these comments.   My server must have some sort of protection on them and attacking didn't seem to do anything.   I've seen videos of mob grinders you use by attacking armor stands too, so it must be somewhat normal.  I was worried I'd have to dig a hole under it to get it out of my base, but setting the ground on fire with a flint and steel worked nicely.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Single, sparse attacks don't break the armorstand. You must hit it several times in a quick succession (spam attack) to break it.